# How to calculate response percentage and have sum show on a different tab?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a column of yes/no responses. I would like to calculate the percentage of 'yes' responses against a headcount but have this figure appear in a different tab, where the headcount total is located.

What would be the correct formula to use? My 'yes/no' responses are recorded in column K.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If headcount is in cell B2 of your current sheet, you can do something like this:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!K:K,"yes")/B$1
```

Or you can have the text "yes" in a cell and refer to the cell.

[image]

better screenshot

[image]

Comment: Good answer but, C3 on sheet two should reference cell A3 not A2. Also, cells B2 and B3 need to be formatted as a percentage or you need to multiply the result in C2 and C3 by 100.

Comment: You're right. The text for the formula in C3 did not adjust when copied down (like the formula did). I'm getting too used to FormulaText() from XL 2016. I added a better screenshot that also includes the crucial click on the percentage formatting button. That should leave little room for error.